# How to query a huge amount of data from a map efficiently?

Tags: solidity, metamask, mapping

I am working on a strategy game where you can conquer territory. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like (I own the purple land at the middle):
[image]
A map stores a plot object per coordinates (a coordinate is stored as a bytes32):

```
    mapping(bytes32 => Plot) public map;
```

When I draw the map in browser I need to check a big quantity of coordinates and this takes a lot of time. In fact, even if I try to do it in the contract and write a solidity function which iterates over the coordinates for me, this is still pretty slow. A solution I came up with is to create another map which stores informations about a 8*8 square space. A chunk is just a boolean. false = empty, true = at least one chunk. This theoretically allows me to be much faster on empty zones, but this is still pretty slow.
What should I do?

Comment: What information are you storing in the map? The EVM is pretty bad at storing large amount of data. I'd store that type of data off-chain perhaps using something like zk snark for synchronization.

Comment: I am storing a Plot as value (a really simple struct) and a coordinates (serialized as a bytes32) as a key. This represents territories owned by players on a world map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should emit an event once a plot is filled just like `emit PlotClaimed(bytes32 coordinates)` and then [query those events](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract--events) on your script or even do a [subgraph](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/explorer).

Comment: How using events would make my queries faster? I will look into TheGraph. Do you know if it is compatible with any evm chains (eg Cronos)?

Comment: Events are what index calls off chain so it's the only way for you to retrieve information without looping and I think The Graph doesn't support Cronos by now, but you could take a look at their website.